# plot piecewise function in matlab

Tags: probability, matlab

This is my code:

```
p=.2; 
x=-1:20; 
px=p*(1-p).^(x-1).*(x>=1); 
Fx=cumsum(px);
figure; 
subplot(2,1,1); 
stem(x,px);
subplot(2,1,2); 
stairs(x,Fx); 
hold on; 
stem(x,Fx,'w.')
```

I want to draw a circle mark at the right end of each horizontal line on the second subplot. Could someone show me how to do? Thanks in advance~

Things like following figure, but move the circle to the right end of each line.
[image]

Comment: Better at stackoverflow as a programming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`plot`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) or [`scatter`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) to draw the red circles.

Add one of the following instructions at the end of your script, they give the same output.

```
% Option 1: using plot
plot(x+1,Fx,'or');

% Option 2: using scatter
scatter(x+1,Fx,'r');
```

As you can see, my approach was to simply add 1 to every element of `x`. This is essentially shifting your data 1 unit in the `x` direction.

This is what you get:

[image: Scatter circles to the right]